# Rewrite condition and rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have alternative domains for my images. E.g.

```
a0.staging.mydomain.co.jp/images -> tt.staging.mydomain.co.jp/images
.
.
a3.staging.mydomain.co.jp/images -> tt.staging.mydomain.co.jp/images
```

I'm putting the following rewrite rule into my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a[0-3]\.tt\.staging\.mydomain\.co\.jp$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tt.staging.mydomain.co.jp/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working :( Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `tt` in the first domain... use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a[0-3]\.staging\.mydomain\.co\.jp$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tt.staging.mydomain.co.jp/$1 [R=301,L]
```